# Is the ppa:ondrej/php repository safe?

Tags: php, repository

I installed the ppa:ondrej/php repository for php and performed an apt-get upgrade. Little did I know it had a lot of libraries packages installed that I have no idea about, so I was wondering if they are safe to stay on the system or not?

Comment: Are they safe? In what respect?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The PPA is maintained by [Ondřej Surý](https://deb.sury.org/), a Debian developer who has been packaging PHP for Debian since PHP 5. It's up to you whether that fits your own definition of "safe", whatever that is.

Comment: I personally know Ondřej, and I consider him safe :D

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, you'll never know. When using Personal Package Archive (PPA) you're by your own.

There's a post which explains with more detailed caveats :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for